# How can I pass user input to a .txt file in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a contact us page with ReactJS, and want to pass user's input to a .txt file, but can't seem to find any solutions.

How can I do this?

Comment: A browser cannot access the clients filesystem. So what do you want to achieve? What you can do is creating a DOM element and offer it for download to the user

Comment: If your goal is remember user's input later, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).